# Control-A delimiter encoding when piping between two S3 buckets

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am currently working on piping data from S3 raw (txt, pipes as delimiters, excessive spaces) to s3 processed (spaces removed, pipes replaced with caret delimiter. This is my Python script which works fine but I'm trying to convert it into bash.

```
byte_stream=BytesIO(response["Body"].read())

input_df = pd.read_csv(byte_stream, delimiter="|", index_col=False, header=None, encoding='latin-1', low_memory=False)

input_df.to_csv(csv_buffer, sep=chr(1), header=False, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

The output of the python script in a regular text editor would be something like this:

TomDahBomb1999 
SusanSoxMiller2001

when opened in vim it's (^A is highlighted purple):

Tom^ADahA^Bomb^A1999 
Susan^ASox^AMiller^A2001

My bash script:

```
aws s3 cp s3://dev-raw/... - | iconv -t UTF-8 | sed -e 's/ *| */|/g; s/|/^A/g' | aws s3 cp - s3://dev/... --sse
```

But the output comes out in regular text editor as:

Tom^ADahA^Bomb^A1999 
Susan^ASox^AMiller^A2001

And in vim the ^A is no not highlighted, just looks like regular text.

I tried to change the encodings of the stream but I can't seem to figure this out. I am limited to working in stream, so can't save to disk. I am not sure if it's the encoding or if I'm doing the delimiter change is bash incorrectly? If someone could offer some insight into this. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can we please see some samples of the input text that is being processed through your bash script? That will help understand the `sed` transformations.

Answer (score 0):

```
aws s3 cp s3://dev-raw/...bloop.txt - | sed -e 's/ *| */|/g; s/|/\x01/g' | aws s3 cp - s3://dev/...bloop.txt --sse
```

`^A` was incorrect, used `\x01` instead and now everything is working.